# string interpolation in angular index html

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, string-interpolation

I have this angular project and then index.html is the main entry point of the application like any other angular project , it contains the links.

As you can see on the html below there is an interpolation which is the `${environment.code}` that is coming from the environment config.

The value of google tag manager id should be the value of `${environment.code}` but when we check the value in the browser when we run and inspect element it did not get the value of the env code . Any idea how we can solve this one guys ? I already tried dom manipulation, string interpolation etc but nothing seems to work. Thanks for any help and ideas much appreciated.

[image]

#index.html code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=0, must-revalidate"/>
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
  <title>m</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="sec-validation" content="d1343a3ae51-8f7b-4038-bfc8-c56565485456547a4d">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">  
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet">  
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
  new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
  j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
  'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=${environment.code}'+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer',environment.code);</script>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
</head>

<body class="mat-typography dx-viewport">
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=${environment.code}"
  height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

#main.ts code

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

```
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

#environment code

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  appName: 'My App',
  code: 'AGRTSRS-GMSDS'
};
```

Comment: So instead, since you're already importing your `environment` object there, if you were to paste that reference instead over into your app.component.ts (or whatever you're calling the top level component file) and assign it to a public var eg; `public gtm = environment.code;` and change the html to reflect as `id=${gtm}` and you should be good to go.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/tYN1PJC still the same result Sir

Answer (score 0):

Write iframe src as `[src]=` for {} to be evaluated.

Comment: still the same result Sir

Comment: @TimLaunders can you show us the edited line, where `[src]` is used?

Comment: <iframe [src]="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=${environment.code}"
  height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>

Comment: Use backticks ` instead of double quotes " to write the value part of [src] attribute. This allows TS to evaluate the ${} part